# Weirdly written matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

The matrix $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix.

$$A = \left [\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 1  & 1 \\
\end{array} \right ]$$

How can I solve the following equation:

$$X\,A = A+2\,X$$

- Since $X$ is positioned left of $A$, $X$ must be a row vector, am I right? Wolfram refuses to add the vector $2X = 2\cdot(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ to $A$, claims they are of unequal length.

Comment: The $X$ ought to be a matrix of the same dimension as $A$.

Comment: Yes, it is a variable matrix, of the same dimension as $A$.

Comment: I would say unknown rather than variable.

Comment: @hardmath My bad. Meant $3\times3$, haha.

Comment: No problem.  As the Answers explain, matrix $X$ should also be $3\times 3$.

Comment: @hardmath I'll take this moment to ask, is this *always* the case? Say I have the equation $A\,X\,B = C$ where $A$ and $B$ are $3\times 3$ whilst $C$ is $2\times 2$. What dimension is $X$ then?

Comment: It's a consequence of wanting the matrix operations indicated in the equation to be defined.  $XA$ on the left hand side makes sense whenever the number of columns in $X$ equals the number of rows in $A$.  The scalar multiple $2X$ has the same number of rows and columns as $X$.  The most information comes from *adding* $A+ 2X$, which requires the numbers of rows and columns in $A$ to agree with those in $2X$.  Hence $X$ and $A$ must be the same *shape* matrices.

Comment: If $AXB=C$ with $A$ and $B$ each $3\times3$ and $C$ is $2\times2$, then there is no such $X$.  In order for the multiplication to be defined, the number of columns of the left factor must equal the number of rows of the right factor, which means $X$ must be $3\times3$, and the product is $3\times3$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$XA=A+2X\implies X(A-2I)=A\implies X=A(A-2I)^{-1} $$

Observe the rightmost matrix is invertible since $\;2\;$ is **not** an eigenvalue of $\;A\;$

Answer (score 2):

The $X$ must be a matrix of the same dimension as $A$. 
You can rewrite your equation for exmple as 
$$X(A - 2 I) =A$$ where $I$ is the identity matrix. 
You are now faced with the task of solving three times a system of (three) linear equations (yet note the  coefficient matrix is always the same).

Comment: This is a system of 9 linear equations for 9 unknowns.  A good (but pedestrian) way to solve the problem.

Comment: @GEdgar thanks for the remark, of course you are right. What I actually meant to say is that these are three *systems* of (three) linear equations (with the same coefficient) to solve. I meant to stress the similarity to a task OP seems familiar with from a comment. .